# Multiple References Between 2 Tables, one-to-many as well as many-to-many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm just started learning RoR and decided to create a side project to learn more. I've been stuck on this problem for about a week now :(

Basically, I'm trying to set up relationships between 2 tables, Users and Recipes.

2 relationships need to form for the purpose of my app.

1. a recipe is created by a user so it's a one-to-many association.
2. a user can have favourite recipes and a recipe can be favourited by multiple users. So, this is a many-to-many association.

This is what I've done so far.

user model

```
  has_many :recipes
  has_many :user_recipes
  has_many :recipe, through: :user_recipes
```

recipe Model

```
  belongs_to :user, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :user_recipes
  has_many :users, through: :user_recipes
```

user_recipes model

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :recipe
```

user_recipe migration file

```
  t.belongs_to :recipe, index: true
  t.belongs_to :user, index: true
```

recipe migration file

```
  t.belongs_to :user
```

user migration file has nothing related to recipes.

From what I did. I was able to: 
1. assign a user to a recipe (the creator) and check using `recipe.user`
2. assign favourite relationships using `recipe.users << user`

**The problem**
when I type `user.recipes` it tells me which recipes a user has created and not which recipes a user likes. I think there should be a better way to set my associates up to be able to use all functionalities properly.

I'd appreciate all the help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give an alias to your created recipes, so that you don't have to use "user.recipes" to access it.

Edit your user model this way:

replace your row

```
has_many :recipes
```

with something like this:

```
has_many :created_recipes, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: "Recipe"
```

By doing this, you can access the recipes your user created by typing "user.created_recipes", and the recipes your user likes by typing "user.recipes".

Comment: sorry, I couldn't vote up (low reputation) but it works! 
I tried this method before but didn't have much success with it. Turn out it was because I was giving an invalid foreign_key on this line. I didn't realise it has to be something that already exists in the recipe table. 
```has_many :created_recipes, foreign_key: :user_id, class_name: "Recipe"``` 

thanks so much. really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad to help :) Please mark the answer as the solution, so that people can see the problem has been solved.